# Registering types vs containers

Tags: c++, qt, containers, qmetatype, queued-connection

If I register a custom type like the following, for the use in queued connections:

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MyClass);
qRegisterMetaType<MyClass>();
```

I can use the type in queued connection with signals like this one:

```
void MySignal(MyType o);
```

Now I also would like to use the type with signals like this:

```
void MyVectorSignal(QVector<MyType> v);
```

I remember I read somewhere that Qt automatically allows using registered types with containers without explicitely registering the specific type/container combination.

But it didn't work for me. I had to register the container as well:

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QVector<MyType>);
qRegisterMetaType<QVector<MyType>>();
```

Should it work without the latter registration code? Is this actually necessary? Should containers work out of the box?

Answer (score 0):

From [Qt docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE) for Q_DECLARE_METATYPE:

> Some types are registered automatically and do not need this macro:
>
> - Pointers to classes derived from QObject
> - QList, QVector, QQueue, QStack, QSet or QLinkedList where T is a registered meta type
> - QHash, QMap or QPair where T1 and T2 are registered meta types
> - QPointer, QSharedPointer, QWeakPointer, where T is a class that derives from QObject
> - Enumerations registered with Q_ENUM or Q_FLAG
> - Classes that have a Q_GADGET macro

So you don't need to register `QVector<T>`. Just make sure T is a registered meta type.